# ListFragment get the item - NPE

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

when I access a menu item within a ListFragment by `info.position`, I get NullPointerEx. Does anyone know why?

```
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {
                if (mCurrentActionMode != null) {
                    return false;
                }

                mCurrentActionMode = getSherlockActivity().startActionMode(
                        mContentSelectionActionModeCallback);
                view.setSelected(true);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }


 private ActionMode.Callback mContentSelectionActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.delete:
                        delete(item);
                        actionMode.finish();
                        return true;
                    }
                return false;
            }
}



        private void delete(MenuItem item) {
           AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
           Log.i("test", String.valueOf(info.position)); //NPE
        }
```

Comment: you are not getting the item in  private void delete() { ?

Comment: no I'm getting Null pointer exception on `info.position`

Comment: ohh sorry I meant  in above delete function argument MenuItem item is missing. so this delete function is different from   delete(item); ? so where you are initlizing item in your code

Comment: sorry, I missed the argument in delete(), of course there I pass the menu item. Edited above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like that is out of scope where you are trying to use it.

You should get the position in the `onItemLongClick` and pass it down through to your other methods to your delete function.

Comment: Sorry forgot the MenuItem argument in delete(), of course I pass the item down.

Comment: I meant to pass the id/position, not the menu item.  Seems like that would be the easiest way.

Comment: Hm ok, then I would have set a `String position` var within the onClickListener. But how comes the MenuItem in callback cannot be used here? Why do so much example in the web suggest this approach?

Comment: Honestly, I would have thought what yu were trying would work.  I don't understand why it doesn't.  My answer was merely trying to give you a way to work around it.